# Intepretering Special Characters in XLSX Documents

Tags: python, unicode, xlsx

I am using the xlsx Python library to read an XLSX document, but some column data contains special characters like `_x000D_`. How can this be converted to its original form?

Comment: Woa!! 11 questions, no a single answer accepted...

Comment: What is "the xlsx Python library"? It should not leave such sequences undecoded. This is a bug that you should raise with the author.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030522/unescape-xhhhh-xml-escape-sequences-using-python

Answer (score 4):

If `_x000D_` is supposed to represent a unicode character with a hex code point, you could use a regular expression expression to find them and a callback function to convert them to the appropriate value.

```python
import re

input_string = "H_x00E9_llo W_x00D8_rld!"

def parse_escaped_character_match(match):
    return unichr(int(match.group(1), 16))

print re.sub("_x([0-9A-F]{4})_", parse_escaped_character_match, input_string)
# prints "Héllo WØrld!"
```